# Div with background image full

Tags: css, background-image

So I've a problem with my code of header, the background image sometimes are 100% but if I refresh the page, a part of image it's make blank, like a crop and sometimes my image isn't loaded.

For header I've this code.

```
    min-height: 702px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
     background: url('img/bgHeaderpsdtohtml.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.img/bgHeaderpsdtohtml.png', sizingMethod='scale');
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/bgHeaderpsdtohtml.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
     border-bottom:9px solid $galben;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
```

The problem looks like - http://i62.tinypic.com/10frxbk.png

I want to use same method to make some divs full screen inside of my page.. Where's the problem?

What I want it's to have a simple div with background image full width and height set of me.. which method is correct?

JsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/53nbe75n/

Answer (score 0):

Change display to inline-block, 
Check  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53nbe75n/1/)

```
 min-height: 702px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I've tried you suggestion but I've the same problem if reload page, the part of image above disappear..

Comment: well, mine isn't! weird...hmm